# QML In a GridLayout, how to constraint a cell with an invisible to have a 0 height?

Tags: qt, qml, grid-layout

I've got a GridLayout laid out this way:

AAAA
C D
C E
C E
C E
C F
C G
HHHH

E has `Layout.fillHeight: true`, F has a preferredheight,
D and G can be hidden and have a preferredHeight set based on their content:

```
Item {
    Layout.row: 2
    Layout.column: 2            
    Layout.columnSpan: 1
    Layout.rowSpan: 1

    id : D
    visible : false
    Layout.preferredWidth : layConfig.implicitWidth + 10
    Layout.preferredHeight : layConfig.implicitHeight + 10
    anchors.margins : 20
    Grid {
        id : layConfig
        ...
        }
```

When D and G are **visible** they are sized correctly.
But when they are **invisible** they are replaced by **an empty space** instead of a 0 height cell.

AAAA
C 
C 
C E
C E
C F
C G
HHHH

While this expected:

AAAA
C E
C E
C E
C E
C F
C G
HHHH

For now, I just added an extra ColumnLayout in the GridLayout for managing the elements D->G.
In a shortterm it is working but on a longer term it will complicate the whole code.

How can I force, with a pure GridLayout, a 0 height in the case a cell is hidden?

Comment: I don't think I understand what your desired result is. In your final diagram, do you prefer that EEFG are all shifted up into the blank cells where DE resided in the first diagram? That is, you want them shifted up 2 rows? If so, you will have to manually re-arrange the children of the GridLayout to do this. GridLayouts enforce that all cells of a row are the same height, so making the contents of a cell invisible does not remove the now-empty cell.

Comment: I edited my example. I wish that when D is invisible, E (which is at fullHeight:true) occupies the place left by D. That the row 2 just collapses to a 0 height, instead of that height that I don't control. And that's ok, for the column C as there is a rowspan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are setting the `preferredHeight` of the D cell already, you can extend the binding for that to include the visibility of the cell:

```
Layout.preferredWidth : D.visible ? layConfig.implicitWidth + 10 : 0
```

As you are not showing the rest of your code, it is possible some additional tweaking is needed, but this should get a step further. For example, the `rowSpan` might have to be adjusted for C, and maybe you are using `Layout.row`?